# How do I save the extracted Email IDs in an excel sheet using Python, that too in a row?

Tags: python-3.x, outlook

```
outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

your_folder = mapi.Folders['email@outlook.com'].Folders['Blah']

blah_inbox = your_folder.Items

f = open("email_txt.csv", "w")

for message in blah_inbox:
    if message.Class == 43:
        if message.SenderEmailType == 'EX':
            print(message.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress)

            f.write(message.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress)

        else:
            print(message.SenderEmailAddress)
```

I opened a new fie and wrote it to a csv, but I get the following result.

```
user1@outlook.comuser2@outlook.comuser3@outook.com.....
```

However, I need the result to be like the below

```
user1@outlook.com
user2@outlook.com
user3@outlook.com
```

Comment: You should look for some Python library that can work with Excel sheets, for example [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to figure this out, I want to get the resultant email IDs in rows in either csv or excel format. Sorry about the noob question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Simple solution is the following

```
f = open("email_txt.csv", "w")

for message in blah_inbox:
    if message.Class == 43:
        if message.SenderEmailType == 'EX':
            print(message.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress)

            f.write(message.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress + '\n')

        else:
            print(message.SenderEmailAddress)
```

I added a "\n" to the end of the write command

Alternatively, since my whole intention was to save in a CSV with some sort of headers. Below is what worked for me. This is the entire code.

```
Todays_Mail = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(hours=24)
Todays_Mail = Todays_Mail.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')
# Connect to Outlook inbox
outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

your_folder = mapi.Folders['email'].Folders['Blah']

blah_inbox = your_folder.Items

blah_inbox = blah_inbox.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + Todays_Mail + "'")

f = open("email.csv", "w")
f.write('Emails,Index\n')

index = 0
for message in blah_inbox:
    if message.Class == 43:
        if message.SenderEmailType == 'EX':
            print(message.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress)
            f.write(message.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress + ',' + str(index) + '\n')
            index = index + 1


        else:
            print(message.SenderEmailAddress)
f.close()
```

The above will give you two columns, one with the header Email, and the second would be a column with the header Index.